# Shorten Properties.Settings.Default to smaller variable

Tags: c#

(before closing as duplicate, please read: I've looked through similar topic, but there is not enough explanation where the code should execute)

I want to set `Properties.Settings.Default` to a shorter variable while form is loaded..

```
    public Object xx;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        xx = Properties.Settings.Default;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(xx.something_name);
    }
```

I get errors later, while calling `xx.something_name`...  How to do that successfully?

Comment: Please post details about the error you are encountering.

Comment: `I get errors later,` is not very helpful.  is `something_name` string?

Comment: @Plutonix let's say, string...  (i have different options like that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store `xx` with the correct type, not as `Object`:

```
private Properties.Settings xx;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    xx = Properties.Settings.Default;
}
```

Comment: I get `Error CS0052 Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Settings' is less accessible than field 'Form1.xx'`

Comment: I had to change that from `Public` to `Private`!  Thanks!

Comment: ah sorry... by default, Settings classes are generated with an internal access modifier. You can change the generation, or you can declare the variable as private or internal. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You get an error as you are assigning to `Object`. Make `xx` of type `Properties.Settings`.

```
public Properties.Settings xx;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    xx = Properties.Settings.Default;
}
```